# It seems that the default for BULK INSERT is Tab delimited input data?

Tags: sql-server

I can't see any text in the Microsoft documentation about "BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)" that states that the default is Tab delimited data.

Or am I missing spotting this information in the documentation pages?

It seems that the default for BULK INSERT is Tab delimited input data?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms188365(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

e.g. this code:

```
SET @Path = @Path + @FileName

-- Build Repository from Import file 
EXEC ('BULK INSERT #TempProviders FROM "' + @Path + '"')
```

Comment: Why are you reading the 2005 version documentation?

Comment: Fair comment .. Google search must have taken me 2005 version info somehow .. better link in answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default field termination for BULK INSERT is, Tab, as mentioned in the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> FIELDTERMINATOR ='field_terminator' Specifies the field terminator to
> be used for char and widechar data files. The default field terminator
> is \t (tab character). For more information, see Specify Field and Row
> Terminators (SQL Server).

Comment: Thanks ! .. I hadn't spotted ... I think I searched for "Deliminated" or similar.  Terminology !

Answer (score 1):

I am using this. Maybe you can just make some adjustments:

```
BULK INSERT Database.dbo.Table
    FROM 'C:\Path\MyFile.csv'
    WITH
    (
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
    )
GO
```

Comment: Thanks ... A bit more info and an example ... and a hint to look for terminology as per FIELDTERMINATOR instead of delimitator or separated by ..